# In a real life system of waving a bubble wand or baton around how do you determine when chaos has occurred?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, chaos-theory, bubbles

In a real life system of waving a bubble wand or baton around how do you determine when chaos has occurred?

Comment: care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Chaos, put simply, is used to describe a system that small changes in the initial conditions result in large differences as time progresses.

In your bubble wand scenario, the chaotic behavior is often due to a large pressure combined with some sort of resistance/shear factor. So, to answer your question, chaotic behavior with the bubbles would be achieved when you swing the wand with a significant force, resulting in pressure on the bubbles. This combined with the air resistance would give chaotic behavior.

Werner Lauterborn did quite a bit of work on the nonlinear dynamics of bubbles in the 70s, you could look into that if you are still curious.

Comment: This does not seem to address the question which asks *how* chaos occurs but for *how to determine* this.

Comment: I figured if they knew what it was they'd be able to come up with a way to determine it themselves! I guess I feel like that kind of critical thinking is really good for you. Scientific method and such..

Comment: wait, so chaos occurs basically every time you swing the bubble wand?

Comment: That is my understanding

Comment: But arguably a hand swing is rather large - far from "Tiny perturbation that would cause large changes in the future"  (?)

Comment: I don't think the tiny perturbations come from the magnitude of the swing, but rather small differences in the magnitude of the swing can lead to surprisingly variant results

Answer (score 0):

*Note that I am not exactly sure what your example systems are, but it doesn’t really matter for the answer that much.*

The central feature of chaos is that a tiny perturbation a system’s state (the initial condition) can cause large changes in the future. To directly demonstrate this in a natural system, you would have to be able to copy it, which is obviously impossible.
Thus, you have to resort to one of the following:

- Reproduce an initial condition with high accuracy (nature throws in the perturbation for free) and observe whether the behaviour fundamentally changes.
  For example, this can be done with some double pendulums, where it is possible to fix both legs in some position and release them almost instantly.
  If the excitation of the pendulum is sufficiently large, you can see very quickly that the behaviour differs on each run.
  For many systems, this is impossible.
- Simulate the system.
  If you have an adequate simulation of the system, i.e., one that reproduces your observation, all you have to do is to check whether this simulation is chaotic, which is rather easy.
- Exclude other possible dynamics.
  Bounded deterministic dynamic systems only have a limited number of possible dynamic behaviours, namely standstill (fixed point), periodicity (limit cycle), quasiperiodicity, and chaos, as well as convergence to one of these dynamics (transients).
  Fixed-point dynamics and periodic ones with a short period are usually easy to spot.
  Quasiperiodic ones or periodic ones with a high period length require special conditions and are thus rather unlikely.
  Moreover they tend to occur in the vicinity of chaos parameter-wise, i.e., a tiny change of parameters can make such a dynamics chaotic.
  Thus if your system exhibits a behaviour that looks like chaos (not converging to a fixed point or limit cycle), chaos is likely to be around.

  Note though that Most interesting real dynamics is some sort of transient, and transients can in turn be chaotic.
  For example, a real double pendulum’s dynamics is a transient to the fixed point when the oscillation has ceased due to friction.
  Thus, when following this approach you have to make up your mind what effects you consider of interest.
- Apply methods from non-linear time-series analysis.
  Briefly, you record some observables of your system over time and estimate relevant dynamic characteristics (such as Lyapunov exponents) which tell you whether chaos has occurred.
  Roughly speaking determining Lyapunov exponents this way is a (much more) sophisticated variant of the first approach:
  You search whether similar states have occurred on your record and see whether they diverge.

In all of these approaches, you should be aware that chaos can be:

- inherent to the system, i.e., the system would exhibit chaos if perfectly isolated,
- only reflect the chaoticity of external systems – which is often regarded just as noise and inherently indistinguishable from it,
- arise from the interaction with an external system itself.

If you only care about inherent chaos, you have to assure yourself that the system is isolated sufficiently well that whatever effect you are observing cannot have arisen due external influences.

Comment: The example I see are always simple mechanical systems driven by known forces (usually just gravity). What if the system is a bunch of floating bubbles with one person's two hands trying to grab the bubbles? The problem then is there are other variable constraints such as the person's agility abilities, whether they see certain bubbles, etc.

Comment: In that case you have to include the person into the system and the main source of chaos is arguably in that person’s brain.

Comment: So basically because the person's actions are not choreographed or pre-defined, their motions would necessarily and sufficiently cause chaos (?)

Comment: @ina: A person’s action do not *cause* chaos, they *are* chaotic.